# Can't see folder in TFS

Tags: tfs

We have a folder checked into TFS. Every developer on the team can see the folder but 1 developer can't.

1. We checked permissions and they look the same for everyone.
2. I tried to "Get Latest" and "Get Specific Version" with overwrite everything options checked.
3. I tried to enable show deleted folders.

Strangely I just can't see this folder on this 1 machine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The developer accidentally dragged the folder and it was marked as "rename" in TFS. We didn't realize it until we tried to check in...